# bootstrapValidator-enable and disable field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator, jqbootstrapvalidation

So; I tried to check couple of solutions online but I couldn't find a solution that solve my problem regarding enabling and disabling field validation using bootstrapvalidator.

I have a field that supposed to give error when someone enter a negative number (e.g -4,-100,-545 etc.), and any number that is not numeric (e.g 4.4.4, 4.r, 4t etc).
But I want to put a condition that wont give error when a user type in -999.

Code is working well when a user enter other number that is not a negative and nob-numeric. And if a user enters negative or non-numeric number, error is displayed. The problem when user enters -999 it validate true(don't show error), but if user change number(-999) to other number such as negative number and nun-numeric number, my field validation stop working (meaning don't show any error though it was supposed to show).

So how can I enable and disable field validation or setting up a condition on field validation to solve my problem using bootstrapValidator..???

Hope you guys have already come across with such a problem and I hope you can help me solve the puzzle.

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/os3b0dqx/ to see how it works

```
my template.html looks like:
<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="myform">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Length</label>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="length" name="length" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div> 
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
feedbackIcons: {
validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'    
 },
fields: { 
length: {
validators: {
greaterThan: {
value:0,
message: 'The value must be greater than or equal to zero'
 },
numeric: {
message: 'The value is not a number',
thousandsSeparator: '',
decimalSeparator: '.'
},
notEmpty: {
message: 'Please fill the length' }
}
},
}
}).on('click keyup input change','[name="length"]',function(){
if ($(this).val() == -999) {
$('#myform').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators','length',false);
  }
else{
$('#myform').bootstrapValidator('validateField','length');
//$('#myform').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators','length',true);
// both "validateField" and "enableFieldValidators" doesn't work for me..
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this `if ($(this).val() == -999)`   to `if ($(this).val() == '-999')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @trushar widetech; but your solution didn't solve the problem. What I'm trying to do is to revalidate my field after entering -999. See the problem; before entering -999 field validation work perfect fine, but after entering -999, if i change that number (-999) to any other number let say -8 or 67f or 6.7.7 field validation doesn't display error message. Seems ($('#myform').bootstrapValidator('validateField','length');) don't revalidate my field

Comment: can you add your code in snippet so i can understand what you exactly want